# Laravel unique foreign key mysql

Tags: laravel, key, row, unique

I have a laravel application with a mysql database
I need to make a unique query, where more than one column in the table is unique with another causing unique rows.  I want to include a foreign key in this.
How do I do this?
I have tried doing
$ table -> unique etc but I can't get the foreign key working 
I am getting an error saying that the foreign key doesn't exist. 
Can anyone please help

Comment: Do you understand the concepts of keys in mysql? Your question isn't clear please provide more explanation with some code

Comment: My code is: $table->unique(array ('sales', 'cost', 'revenue_id'));

Comment: Did you take a look at [the official documentation about migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations) ? I think it is pretty well explained. There is a part about indexes and foreign key constraints.

Comment: The revenue_id os a foreign key from another table. When I migrate the table, an error comes up saying that the revenue_id does not exist. But it is aa foreign key in that table

Comment: In your case `sales`, `cost` and `revenue_id` must be columns of your table. Are they?

Comment: Yes they are. However, the revenue_id is a foreign key